# How to ignore injected input in only one window?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook, sendmessage

I have two devices that create keyboard input, one of them is a real keyboard and the other uses SendInput() to send Injected keyboard input. I am modifying an existing program that uses a hook to send the keyboard message only to its own window and blocks the input globally to other programs. However I do not want the Injected input to be blocked, and I also don't want the program to process the Injected input.

I used a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook to determine if the input is Injected, Then I used a global WH_KEYBOARD hook to send the message only to the window if it is the real keyboard. What I am looking for is a way to sendMessage() to everything except the main window. I couldn't find a method in the documentation to do this though, so I decided to pass the hook farther down.

```
// WH_KEYBOARD
static LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code < 0) {
        return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    //Report the event to the main window, but do not pass it to the hook chain
    if (realKeyboard) {
        SendMessage(hwndServer, WM_HOOK, wParam, lParam);//only listen to real keyboard, block emulated one
    }
    else {
    //what i want is to sendMessage to everythng except the main window
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam); //let injected keyboard passthrough
    //however we want to ignore injected inputs in the main window(keyboard program).
    }
    return 1; 
}
```

I created a local WH_GETMESSAGE hook using GetCurrentThreadId(), to see if I could ignore the injected input there.

```
// WH_GETMESSAGE
static LRESULT CALLBACK GetMessageProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code < 0) {
        return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (!realKeyboard) {
        MSG * info = (MSG *)lParam;
        info->message = WM_NULL;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I read somewhere that info->message = WM_NULL; would work to block the message but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I also Tried creating a message loop something like this but it didn't work either.

```
while (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            if(IsRealKeyboard()){
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }   
    }
```

Any ideas how I can ignore the injected message only in the main window and let it through to the rest of the system?

Comment: `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` tells you if input events are injected (such as by `SendInput()`) via the `LLKHF_INJECTED` and `LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED` flags in the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` struct, but it will not tell you the destination of the input, as [it doesn't know yet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773), so you can't really make decisions about blocking events inside of hooks based on which window may or may not process them later, because the active window may change before the events reach it

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RAW INPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input) in the target window and process the `WM_INPUT` message, then get the Raw Input buffer via [`GetRawInputData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdata).